# Spring Security weblogic js loading

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-security, weblogic, weblogic11g

I have web app with Spring security.

When I run my app on `tomcat9` all works fine, but when 
I use oracle Weblogic something goes wrong and my js scripts in app doesnt work.

Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:7001/ais/s/lib/datetime/js/moment-with-locales.min.js' because its MIME type ('`application/octet-stream`') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

this is my security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserService service;


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/s/**").permitAll() 
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .permitAll();
    }




    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth
        .userDetailsService(new UserDetailServiceImpl(service));
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe for weblogic, you need some extra configuration. Did you have any `WEB-INF` folder in your project ?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna Yes ,  I have my /s/ folder with js css, /views/

Comment: and xml : dispatcher-servlet, web , weblogic, jdbc, tiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solve it by putting to SecurityConfig this

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
  web.ignoring().antMatchers("/s/**");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a weblogic deployment descriptor in WEB-INF folder.Build your project and deploy. In my case my xml look like.
`weblogic.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
  <jsp-descriptor>
    <keepgenerated>true</keepgenerated>
    <debug>true</debug>
  </jsp-descriptor>
  <container-descriptor>
    <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
  </container-descriptor>
  <context-root>/ContextRootOfYourApp</context-root>
</weblogic-web-app>
```